# Differences between shut up and shut down

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

This is my first message here, please, excuse me if I make any mistakes.

I´m learning new phrasal verbs and I´m not sure of the differences between to shut up and to shut down regarding a business. Look at these two sentences:

**I plan to shut down my business next month**

**They shut the shop up for a fortnight**

Why do I have to change the preposition? Is it, maybe, because in the first case the business won´t be reopened?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should find this useful. Note that it allows a more flexible interpretation of the phrase than is given in James's answer.  I've come across both: **to shut up THE shop**, meaning to lock up, and **to shut up shop** indicating temporary or permanent closure.
 https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shut-up-shop

Answer (score 2):

"Shut down" means a complete stopping of work. You would use this if the shop is going bankrupt, or if you are closing for a long period of time. It's also used when you turn off a computer completely.

"Shut up" means lock the doors and secure the building, but you expect to be back to work the next day. It is also used to mean "close your mouth", in a rather rude way.

So the two phrases have different meanings.  One is about stopping work, and the other is about locking the doors.

Comment: Thank you very much. That´s what I thought, but I needed a confirmation :-).